# How to run Sbt in IDEA with Merging?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-assembly

When I run the build in TeamCity with command:

```
;set test in assembly := {};clean;compile;flywayClean;flywayMigrate;assembly
```

I get merge errors:

> TraceEvent(Error, java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different
> file contents found in the following:
>
> /home/teamcity/tcagent/system/sbt_ivy/cache/org.joda/joda-convert/jars/joda-convert-2.2.1.jar:module-info.class
> /home/teamcity/tcagent/system/sbt_ivy/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/bundles/jackson-databind-2.11.0.jar:module-info.class
> /home/teamcity/tcagent/system/sbt_ivy/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/bundles/jackson-annotations-2.11.0.jar:module-info.class
> /home/teamcity/tcagent/system/sbt_ivy/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/bundles/jackson-core-2.11.0.jar:module-info.class

However, when I do this locally in IDEA, I don't get such errors.

Probably Idea runs sbt without merging. How can I fix this to get the same errors in Idea?

Comment: Which command is running in TeamCity?

Comment: ;set test in assembly := {};clean;compile;flywayClean;flywayMigrate;assembly

Answer (score 0):

I created sbt task in IDEA with command:

```
;set test in assembly := {};clean;compile;assembly
```

and it worked.